# Перевод машинного кода (кодировка)

Tags: php, c#, post

Программа должна передать POST запрос серверу, после чего PHP скрипт отображает данные этого запроса.

Программа отправляет файл, предварительно убедившись, что он весит 40кб. Но в переменной `$_POST[param]` доходит только 15кб. Данные передаются в UTF8 кодировке. Если передавать цифры [0..9], то они прекрасно доходят и по 100кб. Вот команда для отображения:

```
echo $_POST[param];
```

Вот исходник программы на C#:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(postUrl);
request.Method = "POST";
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();

var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"Data");
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

using (var newStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    Console.Writeline(bytes.Length); //Размер ДО отправки (равен 40кб)
    newStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    newStream.Close();
}

Console.Writeline(
    new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8)
        .ReadToEnd()
        .Length);
//Размер ПОСЛЕ отправки (равен 15кб)
```

Comment: Эээ... А где тут, простите, машинный код? о_О

Comment: Он читает исполняемый файл под названием "Data", который лежит в корне программы, переводит в массив байтов и отправляет в качестве POST запроса

Comment: Это я понял, а где тут машинный код всё же?

Comment: Попробуйте указать заранее размер пересылаемых данных: `request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;`. И я не понял, какое отношение к проблеме имеет размер респонса?

Comment: Что значит "указать" ? В смысле добавить в код эту строчку? Так она и так есть, а если вывести на экран - то 40кб и будет. Размер респонса - это и есть размер файла, который был получен сервером: он куда меньше, чем исходный файл (40кб против 15кб).

Comment: Строчку не заметил, прощу прощения. Сервер в респонс записывает этот же файл? Иначе как его размер может совпадать с размером посылаемого файла?

Answer (score 1):

Судя по коду, файл отправляется как есть, а не как параметр. Где-то в этом файле есть фрагмент, начинающийся с букв `param=`, и заканчивающаяся на `&` либо идущая до конца файла. Вот этот фрагмент после раскодирования и оказывается в 15 Кб.

Если вам нужно запихнуть файл в параметр целиком, то вам надо сначала применить к ему URL-кодирование, а потом дописать в начало `param=`. Подробности можно прочитать в описании формата `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: Да, точно! Останавливается прям на знаке '&'. Тогда мне нужно " var bytes = encoding.GetBytes(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(postedData));" примерно так сделать? Тогда в PHP мне надо расшифровывать как-то? Он не видит этот параметр теперь.

Comment: Все! Надо было так сделать:  var bytes = encoding.GetBytes("CookieVar=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(postedData));